# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar el último registro de una tabla mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

En la imagen vemos como resultado 4 registros pero en realidad son dos registros como rutas.

Solo que la tabla trayectos ya registró 2 coordenadas para cada ruta.
 ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar solo las dos rutas con la última coordenada?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las dos rutas con la última coordenada son las del nombre 'Salesiano'?

Comment: El valor de `id_ruta` ¿es el que utilizas para definir cuál es el "último" registro?

Comment: id_trayecto con ese defino cual sea el ultimo

Comment: Las dos rutas son Cristo Rey y la otra es Salesiano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras intentar no dió resultado, pero se hizo de la siguiente manera y sí funcionó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @JhonatanGarcia, si de esta forma lo solucionaste sería bueno que marcaras esta respuesta como acertada, para que otros (que puedan tener tu misma duda) puedan encontrar la solución rápidamente.

Comment: Gracias lo había olvidado ya esta como respuesta correcta

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que decis queres quedarte con el registro de id_trayecto mayor para cada id_ruta.

Entonces simplemente hace 
ORDER BY 
id_ruta, id_trayecto DESC
GROUP BY
id_ruta

Perdon pero no recuerdo exactamente la nomenclatura de MySQL

Comment: al hacerla de esta manera me da dos resultados pero no los ultimos ids del trayecto me da como resultado el id_trayecto 3 y id_trayecto 1, y para lo que necesito deberia ser el id_trayecto 2 y el id_trayecto 4

Comment: Perdon Jhonatan, me equivoque al contestarte, ahora edite la respuesta. Solo agrupa por el id_ruta

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! Pero aun siguen los ids 1 y 3, pero ya tengo la respuesta

Comment: ok, me alegro. Saludos